# How to make on Swift-Wkwebview auto fill username and password?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift2, wkwebview

i have one question. I want to make on my application auto fill username password with keychain. Im added Associated Domains on my application but i dont have now which step is needed now for autofill. Im used Swift 3.0. My website input username and password html is;

```
<input type="text" name="user"  placeholder="Username" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off"   aria-invalid="false">

<input type="text" name="password"  placeholder="Password" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off"   aria-invalid="false">
```

Can you give me an idea to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/password-autofill-for-ios-apps-for-faster-login-ios-11-1d9f77deb35a check this

Comment: Thank you for your comment @faris97 , but this solution is for uitextfield components, but for me is needed from wkwebview  store username and password. This solution have on safari browser, but i dont know which step is needed to implements this on the Wkwebview. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_an_html_input_element

It boils down to adding certain keywords to `autocomplete` like this:

```
<input id="user-text-field" type="email" autocomplete="username"/>
<input id="password-text-field" type="password" autocomplete="current-password"/>
```

Comment: @linuxman if this answers your question, please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in WKWebview. At least in iOS 15.